# How to use ConTeXt in a unix pipeline?

Tags: context

I can process my tex file into a PDF by running "context something.tex". It produces an output file called something.pdf and a few other files (such as something.log).

I want to run a command as part of a pipeline, so that the output PDF is written to standard output and all the other temporary files are removed. How could I do that? For example:

```
$ cat something.tex | context <insert magic here> | zathura -
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What is "zathura"?

Comment: @Mico Mupdf-based PDF viewer with intuitive controls: https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/

Comment: @Richard Parsons: There’s [this thread](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2012/067513.html) from 2012 that might help you. But considering that it usually takes multiple Luatex runs to generate the PDF, reading or writing from pipes doesn’t seem to have that many advantages. YMMV.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to write PDF to standard output using pdftex or luatex. If you want to remove all temporary files, you can use `context --purgeall filename`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, since as phg said, you need at least two runs to typeset something with forward references.  I have no idea how to literally do what you asked, but the following might be close enough.

The key is to realize two things: 1) you don't have to accept default file names.  Check the documentation to see how to explicitly give input and output file names.  I only know how to do it in MikTeX, which won't help you.  2) standard input and standard output have perfectly good file names: /dev/stdin and /dev/stdout.  Finally, delete the temporary files manually.  This is easy if you tell TeX to output all aux files in a given directory.  There should hopefully be an option for that too.  (In MikTeX it's -aux-directory.)